# In .NET is there a way to build an OOP object, using Linq, to query XML?

Tags: linq

So I have an XML element car and an XML element mustang. Mustang inherits from car.

Is there any way to automatically allow mustang to inherit from car using Linq?

```
<car>
    <numDoors/>
    <retailPrice/>
    <year/>
    <vin/>
</car>
<sportsCar inherits='car'>
    <hp/>
    <torque/>
</sportsCar>
<mustang inherits='sportsCar'>
    <cobra />
    <featurePackage sql='select featurePackage from mustang where id=@'/>
</mustang>
```

It's basically like that. There is no multiple inheritance. The c# object should be just like you would imagine it to be. That is it would have all the properties of car and sportsCar as well as mustang.

Comment: LINQ is a query language. It's more functional that OOP and it really doesn't have anything to do with inheritance. I think you may need to clarify your question somewhat.

Comment: I am working on a system that uses proprietary software to turn XML elements into objects as described in the car example. We are looking at ways to have the system work using some type of .NET code rather than proprietary code. I know you can use Linq to query XML and I know we could combine Linq with proprietary software to get the job done. I am asking if there is a way, in Linq, to turn OOP classes which are defined in an XML file, into C# objects complete with inheritence.

Comment: So what you just said would be useful in the question. Also providing an actual XML document plus your object model would be helpful too.

Comment: k hold on, ill whip up an example

Comment: Ah, it appears as though you want to dynamically create your object model. Is that right?

Comment: right, based on whatever is in the xml

Comment: You can't create dynamically create classes in a statically compiled language such as C#. You need to define your classes by hand and then map from the XML.

Comment: Although you can use T4 files to generate source code. Do you know about T4 files in Visual Studio?

Comment: I do not. I thought you could create types on the fly with Linq or maybe that was just some properties of a class. Either way, I will read about T4's. Thanks so much for all your help, man.